# MarkLogic : how to use and-query in cts:uris?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I found explanations about `cts:uris` and there are two examples below.

What is difference between them. It seems that they will do the same job, but some say that the latter is better because it is faster.

Please give me a explanation, thank you in advance.

Eample 1:

```
cts:uris(@@@, (), cts:element-value-query(@@@@))
```

Example 2:

```
cts:uris((), (), 
  cts:and-query((
    cts:directory-query(@@@),
    cts:element-value-query(@@@@))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above examples are not the same. It is important to understand that the first argument is just a starting point for the values, but does not limit the end. If you pass in 'b', it will start with 'b*', but continue with 'c*', and beyond. This applies to all lexicon lookups, including `cts:values` and `cts:collections`.

If you need to get uris within a particular path, you are probably better off with [`cts:uri-match`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uri-match).

It is true though that passing in a directory-query as argument can improve performance. That also applies to `cts:uri-match`.

HTH!